# In Ruby on Rails, why does sometime in controller, it is plural and sometime it is singular?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

```
class MoviesController < ApplicationController
  def index
    @movies = Movie.all
  end

  def show
    @movie = Movie.find(params[:id])
    @actors = @movie.actors
  end
end
```

As seen above, in the index action, @movies is used, but in the show action, @movie is used. How does one determine whether it is plural or singular?

Comment: You will need to read about actions in Rails and http verbs they are mapped to. [For starters](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Both `@movies` and `@movie` are instance variables that you choose how to define. In your example, `@movies` is assigned to the whole collection of Movies from your model, therefore it is conventionally assigned a plural variable. `@movie` is assigned to a single record, therefore it's conventionally assigned a singular variable.

You can name your instance variables whatever you want, but Rails heavily favors convention over configuration.

Comment: Indeed. It's not only a Rails conventio,n though. I'd expect `movies` to hold a collection (set, array, list, ...) of `movie` objects in any script in any language.

Answer (score 1):

Adding to @Dithanial's answer,  As you may be familiar when you click on show action only that particular record is displayed. So in the below code snippet:

```
def show
  @movie = Movie.find(params[:id])
  @actors = @movie.actors
end
```

The instance variable @movie find the specific item on based of it's id and displays the content.

Answer (score 0):

In general you use plural in case of an array, and singular in case of a single object.

Answer (score 0):

In the index -- you are getting **all of the movies** so that you can list all of the movies.

In the other controller methods -- you are typically editing a **single movie**.

`@movies` vs `@movies` doesn't actually matter. You could name it `@banana`. However, there are lots of cases like file names (model = singular, controller = plural) and Active Record relations (references) where plurality does matter